# String builder returning the same values

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have 3 string builders which display different values imported from a data table. Currently when the page is rendered I only get the 3 same values for "binType" so "date" etc. have binType values. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
if (binForm.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    int rowCounter = binForm.Rows.Count;
    int increment = 0;
    while (rowCounter > 0)
    {
        tableData.Append("<td>" + binForm.Rows[increment]["binType"].ToString() + "</td>");
        tableData2.Append("<td>" + binForm.Rows[increment]["binColour"].ToString() + "</td>");
        tableData3.Append("<td>" + binForm.Rows[increment]["date"].ToString() + "</td>");
                    increment++;
                    rowCounter--;
                }
            }
            literal.Text = tableData.ToString();
            literal2.Text = tableData.ToString();
            literal3.Text = tableData.ToString();

            connect.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Of course you will get the same result because  tableData.ToString() assigned to literal.Text,literal2.Text and literal3.Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
literal.Text = tableData.ToString();
literal2.Text = tableData.ToString();
literal3.Text = tableData.ToString();
```

It should be:

```
literal.Text = tableData.ToString();
literal2.Text = tableData2.ToString();
literal3.Text = tableData3.ToString();
```

The difference is that I've specified the 2 and 3 for the other table data objects.

Answer (score 0):

Change below code:

```
literal.Text = tableData.ToString();
literal2.Text = tableData2.ToString();
literal3.Text = tableData3.ToString();
```